# How to geocode multiple address using google geocoder and leaflet and how to geocode the address dynamically into leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to build an application where  users can add their business place online in a map. Instead of using google maps, i'm using leaflet for various reason obviously due to open source and it have no geocoders. I'm using geocoder php to use multiple vendors which is google as primary, yandex as secondary, bing and osm for backup. I want to use these geocoder due their expertise but they provide usage limit so when address geocode reach the limit, the php script run so that we move to next geocoder for those particular days(this part of the plan). Is it possible to do that? And i'm having difficulty as well to geocode address using leaflet geojson and point it to map after it geocode the places address and how to do dynamically if the data to geocode and convert the places' info on the map in form of markers? Really need help on this. Desperate to see if it's work

Comment: This post contains multiple questions, you should narrow its focus. Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: Have try to locate marker via latlng. It works as usual. What i wish is to locate marker to leaflet from address itself. And of course i wish to automate the geocoding process

Comment: Again, too broad to be answered succinctly, which makes it a poor fit for a Q&A format site like SO. I recommend you post the code you've tried and get help with your first blocker.